# how to write a nestled dictionary to csv?

Tags: python, python-3.x

trying to write a nestled dictionary into csv.

what I've tried so far is:

```
csv_file = 'test.csv'
csv_columns = dict_data[0].keys()
try:
    with open(csv_file, 'w') as csvfile:
        writer = csv.DictWriter(csvfile, fieldnames=csv_columns)
        writer.writeheader()
        for data in dict_data:
            writer.writerow(data)
except IOError:
    print("I/O error")
```

but the error I'm getting is:

```
csv_columns = dict_data[0].keys()
KeyError: 0
```

I know it probably has something to do with the the keys that has a list

this is my dictionary:

```
dict_data = {'count': 20240, 
'next': {'limit': 1, 'offset': 1}, 
'previous': None, 

'results': 
[{'id': '334455', 
'custom_id': '112', 
'company': 28, 
'company_name': 'Sunshine and Flowers', 
'delivery_address': '34 olive beach house, #01-22, 612345', 
'delivery_timeslot': {'lower': '2019-12-06T10:00:00Z', 'upper': '2019-12-06T13:00:00Z', 'bounds': '[)'}, 
'sender_name': 'Edward Shine', 
'sender_email': '', 
'sender_contact': '91234567', 
'removed': None, 
'recipient_name': 'Mint Shine', 
'recipient_contact': '91234567', 
'notes': '', 
'items': [{'id': 21668, 'name': 'Loose hair flowers', 'quantity': 1, 'metadata': {}, 'removed': None}, {'id': 21667, 'name': "Groom's Boutonniere", 'quantity': 1, 'metadata': {}, 'removed': None}, {'id': 21666, 'name': 'Bridal Bouquet', 'quantity': 1, 'metadata': {}, 'removed': None}], 
'latitude': '1.37315509207642000000', 
'longitude': '103.76570152476201000000', 
'created': '2019-08-15T05:40:30.385467Z', 
'updated': '2019-08-15T05:41:27.930110Z', 
'status': 'pending', 
'verbose_status': 'Pending', 
'reschedule_requests': [], 
'signature': None}]}
```

Comment: `dict_data` isn't a list; it's a dictionary.  Accessing `dict_data[0]` means you're looking for a _key_ of `0`, which doesn't exist.

Comment: dict_data has no key 0, the list in dict_data['results'] has a 0th item.

Comment: as above dict_data is not a list or tuple, so has no element [0].  `dict_data.keys()` will give 'count, next, previous, results' But `for data in dict_data writer.writerow(data)` will not work either. How should the csv file look like?

Comment: CSV is by its very nature a linear format. There are hacks to put columns within columns but these are really just an abuse of everyone's time and sanity. If your data does not naturally serialize into a flat list of rows with straightforward columns, you should probably not use CSV, or normalize to a *set* of tables which can each straightforwardly be represented as CSV. (See also [*Database normalization* on Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization).)

Comment: I think, you only want the `data` inside the `result` ? So try `data_dict['result'][0].keys()` ?

Answer (score 0):

Tri this

```
csv_file = 'test.csv'
csv_columns = dict_data[0].keys()
try:
    with open(csv_file, 'w') as csvfile:
        writer = csv.DictWriter(csvfile, fieldnames=csv_columns)
        writer.writeheader()
        for data in dict_data:
            writer.writerow([data])
except IOError:
    print("I/O error")
```